# Google chrome: select element contents still visible after blur

Tags: html, jquery, google-chrome, focus, jquery-events

I have a form, containing a `<select>` element containing options which are changing according to another field value.

So, when the `<select>` item gains focus if the other field value is not set blur event is triggered on the previous, and focus is triggered on the latter.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#requiresOuterValue', 
function() {
    if( isNaN(parseInt( $('#outerValue').val() )) )
    {
        $('#outerValue').trigger('focus');
    }
});
```

The code works fine (dropdown content disappears, #outerValue gains focus) in Firefox but not in chrome, where #outerValue gains focus, but the `<select>` item contents are displayed as well.

Comment: You should post the code that does not work in chrome and not the code that already works

Comment: @Jonathan: the code i posted alredy is what is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/C9rKL/

Comment: then reword your question, you are saying the element gain focus but is not hiding, but the code to hide is not present...

Comment: I tested your code and does exactly what is supposed to, in chrome if `isNaN(parseInt( $('#outerValue').val()))` is true `#outerValue` gains focus, where is the problem?

Comment: @Jonathan: i just noticed stackoverflow "strips" items enclosed in &lt; and &gt;... i used the $lt;selected&gt; tag many times.

Comment: You are still missing the code used to hide elements, or your question is badworded and what you need is the `select` to be not open until `outerValue` has value?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm.. Did you tried to use the native 'focus' method instead the 'focus' jquery event?

```
$('#outerValue')[0].focus();
```

I'm not sure that triggering jQuery events have implicit browser native behaviours.

Comment: the focus works, he's saying that the hide code doesn't work... `the code works fine (dropdown disappears, #outerValue gains focus) in firefox but not in chrome, where #outerValue gains focus, but the item contents are displayed as well.`

Comment: Ops.. It's true :( Sorry.

Comment: No problem, I was falling in the trap too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with a solution.

Your problem is that the closure of a `select` is not standard in all browsers. the only way I found to **simulate** the closure is to re-render the `select`.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#requiresOuterValue', function() {
        var requiresOuterValue = $("#requiresOuterValue").clone();

        if( isNaN(parseInt( $('#outerValue').val() )) )
        {
            $('#outerValue').trigger('focus');
            $("#requiresOuterValue").replaceWith(requiresOuterValue);
        }
});
```

**EDIT:** fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/JonnyMe/C9rKL/1/

### jQuery plugin implementation

You can even implement a jQuery plugin to achieve the goal:

```
$.fn.closeSelect = function() {
    if($(this).is("select")){
        var fakeSelect = $(this).clone();
        $(this).replaceWith(fakeSelect);
    }
};
```

And then use it this way:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#requiresOuterValue', function() {
        if( isNaN(parseInt( $('#outerValue').val() )) )
        {
            $('#outerValue').trigger('focus');
            $("#requiresOuterValue").closeSelect();
        }
});
```